# PHP & SQL match but script still doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having some issues for the last 5 hours. I've been trying to fix it and I can't seem to find a solution, so I hope you can help me!

So I have this vote.php script:

```
<?php
if(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "vote.php") {
    die("403 - Access Forbidden");
}
echo "<h2 class=\"text-left\">Vote</h2><hr/>";
$earnedpoints = false;
$insertnew = false;
$time = time();
$redirect = "";
$account = $mysqli->real_escape_string(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', @$_POST['name']));
$siteid = $mysqli->real_escape_string(@$_POST['votingsite']);
$checkacc = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '$account'");
$countcheckacc = $checkacc->num_rows;
$row = $checkacc->fetch_assoc();
if($countcheckacc == 0 && isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $funct_error =  "This account doesn't exist!";
}
if($row['loggedin'] > 0 && isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $funct_error =  "This account is logged in!";
} elseif ($account == '' && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $funct_error = 'You need to put in a username!';
} elseif(empty($_POST['votingsite']) && isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $funct_error = "Please select a voting site";
} elseif(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $checksite = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."vote WHERE id = ".$siteid."");
    $countchecksite = $checksite->num_rows;
    if($countchecksite == 0 && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $funct_error = "Invalid voting site.";
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(times) as amount FROM ".$prefix."votingrecords WHERE NOT account='' AND NOT account='0' AND account='".$account."' AND siteid = '".$siteid."'") or die('Error - Could not look up vote record!');
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $sitequery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."vote WHERE id = '".$siteid."'");
        $vsite = $sitequery->fetch_assoc();
        $gvp = $vsite['gvp'];
        $gnx = $vsite['gnx'];
        $timecalc = $time - $row['date'];
        if ($row['amount'] == '' || $timecalc > $vsite['waittime']) {
            if($row['amount'] == '') {
                $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ".$prefix."votingrecords (siteid, ip, account, date, times) VALUES ('".$siteid."', '".$ipaddress."', '".$account."', '".$time."', '1')") or die ('Error - Could not insert vote records!');
            } else {
                $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE ".$prefix."votingrecords SET siteid = '".$siteid."', ip='".$ipaddress."', account='".$account."', date='".$time."', times='1' WHERE account='".$account."' AND siteid = '".$siteid."'") or die ('Error - Could not update vote records!');
            }
            $earnedpoints = true;
            if ($earnedpoints == true) {
                if ($account != '') {
                    $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE accounts 
                                                SET $colvp = $colvp + $gvp, 
                                                    $colnx = $colnx + $gnx 
                                                WHERE name='".$account."'") or die ('Error - Could not give rewards. Your site administrator needs to configure the NX and VP settings.');
                }
                $funct_msg = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='.$vsite['link'].'">';
                $redirect = true;
            }
        } elseif($timecalc < $vsite['waittime'] && $row['amount'] != '') {
            $funct_msg = 'You\'ve already voted for '.$vsite['name'].' within the last '.round($vsite['waittime']/3600).' hours!';
            $funct_msg .= '<br />Vote time: '. date('M d\, h:i A', $row['date']);
        } else {
            $funct_error = 'Unknown Error';
        }
    }
}
if($redirect == true) {
    echo $funct_msg;
} else {
    if(isset($funct_msg)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$funct_msg.'</div>';
    }
    if(isset($funct_error)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$funct_error.'</div>';
    }
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from ".$prefix."vote");
    if($query->num_rows == 0){
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Your administrator has not added any voting sites yet!</div>";
    } else {
        echo "
        <form method=\"post\">
        <div class=\"form-group\">
        <label for=\"voteSite\">Select Site:</label>
        <select name=\"votingsite\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"voteSite\" required>
        <option value=\"\" disabled selected>Select Site...</option>";
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value=\"".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>
        </div>";
        if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"15\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Username\" required autocomplete=\"off\"/><br/>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" maxlength=\"15\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"".$_SESSION['name']."\" value=\"".$_SESSION['name']."\" required autocomplete=\"off\"/><br/>";
        }
        echo "
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit &raquo;\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"/>
            </form>";
    }
}
```

I have this in votingrecords table in SQL: `ip, account, date, times, amount`. It's correct.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I type my username to vote for the game, I'm getting this error message "Error - Could not look up vote record!".

Here's the code for this error:

```
else {
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, SUM(times) as amount 
                                FROM ".$prefix."votingrecords 
                                WHERE NOT account='' 
                                AND NOT account='0' 
                                AND account='".$account."' 
                                AND siteid = '".$siteid."'") or die('Error - Could not look up vote record!');
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $sitequery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."vote WHERE id = '".$siteid."'");
    $vsite = $sitequery->fetch_assoc();
    $gvp = $vsite['gvp'];
    $gnx = $vsite['gnx'];
    $timecalc = $time - $row['date'];
```

I hope you guys can help me, since I've tried everything and cannot get it to work

Comment: php's error reporting and checking for errors on the queries could help shed some light on all this. As would looking at the html source and `var_dump()`.

Comment: There are no errors showing, just the error message defined in the code `or die('Error - Could not look up vote record!');`

Comment: that isn't helping you. You need to check for the *real* error(s).

Comment: do you set $prefix anywhere?

Comment: Set to catch and display http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and [`mysqli_error($mysqli)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) on the queries, with an `if($X_query){...}` for all which might have knocked off a few hours ;-)

Comment: If you cannot output a useful error message Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Yes, $prefix is defined and it equals to "bit_" so the table is called bit_votingrecords. @RST

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping.
I got this issue fixed by executing this `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` in MYSQL.
This would not happen if @RiggsFolly didn't tell me to use this code to display real useful errors, so thank you.

Thanks all!

Comment: Please dont use answers to say thank you. You will only get downvotes. Instead its totally ok to post an answer stating a fix, and even to accept your own answer